# Мгновенный тригер

Tags: javascript

Как сделать мгновенный тригер?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('#button-account').trigger('click');
  },1000);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: убрать setTimeout

Comment: а что в вашем понимании `мгновенный`? Который выполнятся когда страница загрузилась? Или сразу когда открылась? В чем суть?